# Actionbar.getHeight() returning different values between API 16 and 17

Tags: android, height, android-actionbar

I need to set a View's `topMargin` by the `Actionbar` height so it's visible under the `Actionbar`. I do this in my `onCreateOptionsMenu`, thinking the `Actionbar` is drawn at that point. My app targets API 14 and above only.

Running an emulator with API 17, `getHeight()` returns a good value of 96dp. But running the same code on an emulator with API 16, a height of zero is returned, likely because it hasn't been drawn yet.

Why would there be a difference between the two APIs?

Comment: You can try to get the height only when view is drawn. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8171014/1306419 to see how to listen for when the view is actually drawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read it from:

```
?android:attr/actionBarSize
```

Check this post for more information:

[What is the size of ActionBar in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165830/what-is-the-size-of-actionbar-in-pixels)