# Convert Any view into image and save it

Tags: android, android-framelayout

can any one please help me to know how to capture contents of a `FrameLayout` into an image and save it to internal or external storage.

how can convert any view to image

Comment: You mean print screen ?

Comment: NO. Convert layout into an image..

Comment: `FrameLayout` is a layout, image is an image. They are quite different. How can I convert an apple to an orange ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

try this to convert a view (framelayout) into a bitmap:

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

then, save your bitmap into a file:

```
try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/path/to/file.png");
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        output.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

don't forget to set the permission of writing storage into your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Be sure to close the stream in case of an exception; I'd recommend adding a `finally` block to close the stream and recycle the bitmap.

Comment: doing same method the image get saved but image is all black any idea what mistake did i make..

Comment: So I did this with a framelayout but the width and height was not able to be obtained, using a `ViewTreeObserver` I was able to get the info after it rendered from from inside onCreate.  This worked great for thank you. for more info see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8171014/1815624

Comment: You could make this more efficient by calling `view.getDrawingCache(true/false)`, because the view drawing may already be cached. Then, if `getDrawingCache()` returns null, call `Bitmap.createBitmap()` as you have it. For more info see the docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache(boolean)

Comment: @GhoRiser I trying with framelayout but all the time I am getting framelayout width as the screen size how can I resolve it /

Answer (score 9):

try this...

```
public static void saveFrameLayout(FrameLayout frameLayout, String path) {
    frameLayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    frameLayout.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap cache = frameLayout.getDrawingCache();
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path);
        cache.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.flush();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } finally {
        frameLayout.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... for making efforts..

Comment: @Gopal Gopi I trying with framelayout but all the time I am getting framelayout width as the screen size how can I resolve it

Comment: @pcpriyanka if your framelayout dimensions are as match_parent, You will get screen size only

Comment: @GopalGopi then What is should be ?

Comment: right now it is fill_parent

Comment: Hi @PriyankaChauhan Its very late but it may helpfull for someone. I got what you want. I found solution. You need to use "frameLayout.getDrawingCache(true);" instead of "frameLayout.getDrawingCache();". Here we are sending true for auto scaling that will provide us scaled image not equivalent to screen width. For more details refer to this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getDrawingCache()

Comment: @GopalGopi Your code is working properly the view is saved as image but when i share the saved image in whatsapp then i am not able to share it. It's showing me The file format is not supported. But i am able to open it in device. Can you check this