# How to add rainbow gradient to an Image in android

Tags: android, colors, android-bitmap

I want to add **Transparent Rainbow or Spectrum Gradient** to `Bitmap`.

In `photoshop` it is very easy. Now I want to do it `programmatically`. I have gone through a lot of research. But gradient has only one `starting color` and one `ending`. How could I add the rainbow color(multiple color) Gradient in Android.

Or is there a way to add that effect to bitmap in Android? Like given

[image]

Comment: see `LinearGradient (float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1, int[] colors, float[] positions, Shader.TileMode tile)`

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use a translucent image with the desired gradient and put it on top of your image view in a `FrameLayout`. then capture bitmap of the view.

[image: gradient]

once you get your layout ready use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21726101/1529129) to capture bitmap from it

> try this to convert a view (framelayout) into a bitmap:
>
> ```
> public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
>     Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
>     Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
>     view.draw(canvas);
>     return bitmap;
> }
> ```

Comment: Rahul I also wanna save it. Your procedure only shows an overlay. but when I save it remains the same

Comment: I will update you after testing it Rahul Tiwari and thanks for your help

Comment: @Nepster I was lazy to put an XML example for solution so I made an image. I invite you to improve my answer with xml snippet ;)