# How can I getHeight of View before removing that View during OnCreate?

Tags: java, android

So it is not really desired to do this during oncreate though it is my thought that the animations I want to use will work much better with an image rather than a FrameLayout.

So What I have figured so far is (by reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406090/1815624), using ViewTreeObserver I am able to use getHeight in the function shown at the bottom which is where the error occurs  where it states `view.getWidth(), view.getHeight()`

Really I just want to get that image of the view and nuke the original with something like `removePieChart(fl);` **Though as soon I used `removePieChart(fl);` the errors happen...**

A timed event may work but it seems like a bad idea...Any suggestions?

Please and Thanks

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final FrameLayout tv = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
        final ViewTreeObserver observer= tv.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                View fl = findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
                image.setImageBitmap(viewToBitmap(fl));
                removePieChart(fl);
//                observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        });
    }
    private void removePieChart(View fl) {
        ((ViewManager)fl.getParent()).removeView(fl);
    }
```

and for reference here is the viewToBitmap method from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21726101/1815624

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/file.png");
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        output.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: may be it worked for u   fl.getMeasuredHeight()

Comment: I tried that and it did not work... thanks for the suggestion..got any more?

Comment: Well views are not *yet* created in the `onCreate()`, so mostly you'll get 0.

Comment: You cannot remove a view that isn't added yet

Comment: Aware that was the reason to use the listener in the first place, as I need it to be rendered copied and destroyed...

Answer (score 2):

```
   **Try this code**

    final LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    final ViewTreeObserver observer= layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout()
            {
                    Log.d("Log", "Height: " + layout.getHeight());
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the following class I snatched a while ago from the since-deleted `Flow-Sample` made by Square:

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;

public final class ViewUtils {
    public interface OnMeasuredCallback {
        void onMeasured(View view, int width, int height);
    }

    public static void waitForMeasure(final View view, final OnMeasuredCallback callback) {
        int width = view.getWidth();
        int height = view.getHeight();

        if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
            callback.onMeasured(view, width, height);
            return;
        }

        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override public boolean onPreDraw() {
                final ViewTreeObserver observer = view.getViewTreeObserver();
                if (observer.isAlive()) {
                    observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                }

                callback.onMeasured(view, view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());

                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private ViewUtils() {
    }
}
```

Then you use it as

```
ViewUtils.waitForMeasure(view, new ViewUtils.OnMeasuredCallback() {
    public void onMeasured(View view, int width, int height) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Do something with height [" + height + "]");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly got to remove the listener `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` so it stop it from repeatedly calling the `removePieChart()` method. Once that is done, you can then remove the view.

So  `onGlobalLayout` get's changed :

```
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            View fl = findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
            image.setImageBitmap(viewToBitmap(fl));
            removePieChart(this); //TODO remove the PieChart resource
        }
```

and also `removePieChart()` is changed

```
private void removePieChart(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener a) {

    final FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
    final ViewTreeObserver observer= fl.getViewTreeObserver();
     observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(a);
    ((ViewManager)fl.getParent()).removeView(fl);
}
```