# Framelayout bitmap with specific width and height

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, android-framelayout

How to use specific width and height for bitmap on saving framelayout to image?

Comment: What do you mean by "saving framelayout to image"?

Comment: @FabioR converting framelayout to image with specific width and height

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "converting". You have a FrameLayout with an image as a background and you want to use pass the image to an ImageView, in example?

Comment: @FabioR I have an framelayout and I add some text on it then convert it to bitmap. Don't you know about converting framelayout to bitmap and save it as an image?

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725916/convert-frame-layout-into-image-and-save-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check following code

```
public Bitmap convertFrameToBitmap(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}


ry {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(getActivity().getFilesDir() + File.separator+ image.png");
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
        output.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```