# make a visting card image and attach it to a email android

Tags: android

I have to make a printable business card as shown in attached image and attach to an email in the form of .png image. I have no idea how I will be making this image in android and attach it to email in .png format

[image: enters the image description here]

on Button click.For your reference I have attached an image of that card over here. Thanks for viewing my post..

Comment: i do not know how i will be making this image through program ..if you have any idea plaese suggest

Comment: are you getting data from server or static data

Comment: i will be getting diff. data according to diff user from the server

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this is make that card into a layout and then fill it in or let the user fill it in (whichever). And then you can use the following piece of code to turn the view into a Bitmap

```
public Bitmap viewToBitmap(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Code is from this question here,

[Convert frame layout into image and save it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725916/convert-frame-layout-into-image-and-save-it)

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
File filePath = new File("/path/file.png");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(filePath);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Email:"));
```

Comment: this thing i know ..my requirement is to make this image dynamically and fill all the detail from program like user image ,user name etc..

Comment: @TulikaKansal Simple, take screenshot of device programatically on share button then use above code to share the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android

Comment: my layout for is image is not attached to any activity and also i need device independent  image  i mean of fixed height and width  like of visting card . how can i get it done ??\

Comment: @TulikaKansal in your first comment, You said you need to make image (card) dynamically, how you will make this, I think there is only one way to make such layout. Please correct me. For this device independent, you can make your own custom layout

Comment: yes my friend  i made my custom layout with a fixed hard coded height and width.and then i used layout inflater to convert that xml file in to java view object as

Comment: ok grt , One thing dont pass harcoded height and width, use wrap content or fill parent, then programmatically take screen shot.

Comment: if fixed height/widht is required, then pass as per screen widht /height as per calculation

Comment: LayoutInflaterinflater(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.emergency_card,null,false); Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap)  view.draw(canvas);
 
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("file.png");
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);output.close();but it is returning me a blank image.

Comment: dear if i will we using match parent for width then as text in design is large  so it is not going to come on single line