# Simple Android app crashes when calling Button Method

Tags: android

When I try to use the button method and test it on the android emulator, it always crashes. If I don't call any methods its work first, but I need to edit it when I program. A simple example is test1, if I comment out test1.getHeight() it works fine, but when I use it, it crashes. Ultimately, I want to be able to edit the height/width.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    final Button [] mainMenuBtn = new Button[10];
    Button test1 = new Button(this);
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }


        int windowWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int windowHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        test1 =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
        test1.getHeight();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

I changed it and it still didnt work. This is my xml

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridLayout0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnCount="4"
     >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</GridLayout>
```

And this is the code, it crashes if I call any method, but it doesnt crash when I new it or add the ID. Its really straight forward, I don't know why it causes this, perhaps its because i using the newest SDK?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {
    ImageView checkBox1;
    ImageButton checkButton1 = new ImageButton(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

         checkBox1 = new ImageView(this);
        checkBox1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        checkButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        final ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObs = checkBox1.getViewTreeObserver();
        viewTreeObs.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                checkBox1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                viewTreeObs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }); 

        //


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_menu,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's in your activity_main.xml layout?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653778/nullpointerexception-accessing-views-in-oncreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be calling `getHeight` too early.

`Button` is populated after the `View` is rendered, and your `Button` is called before `View` is rendered.

Try move your call, `getHeight` around in different methods, other than `onCreate`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get `getHeight()` of a button in `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` but UI has not been sized and laid out on the screen yet. So the problem is creating.
Try it

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
   super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
   height = test1.getHeight();
}
```

**Another Way**

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObs = button.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObs.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        height = test1.getHeight(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still didn't work, I changed it to a setBackgroundColor method.

Answer (score 0):

If it's crashing when calling `getHeight()` it probably means that `test1` is `null`. It would be null if it doesn't exist in your content layout, which in this case is `activity_main`. Also, keep in mind that the button hasn't been measured yet on creation, that happens later on.

See this SO post: [getHeight returns 0 for all Android UI objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170915/getheight-returns-0-for-all-android-ui-objects)