# Android- View height is changing during the running time

Tags: android, view, dimension

I am trying to create dynamic buttons at the center of spesific areas of the ImageView. To figure out center of any area, I am using this function:

```
TextView createButton(int i, String[] boundingBoxArray) {

        String[] coorArray = boundingBoxArray[i].split(",");
        int[] coordinates = new int[4];

        int x11 = Integer.parseInt(coorArray[0].replace(" ", ""));
        int y11 = Integer.parseInt(coorArray[1].replace(" ", ""));
        int x22 = Integer.parseInt(coorArray[2].replace(" ", ""));
        int y22 = Integer.parseInt(coorArray[3].replace(" ", ""));

        coordinates[0] = x11;
        coordinates[1] = y11;
        coordinates[2] = x22;
        coordinates[3] = y22;

        TextView buttonn = new TextView(context);
        buttonn.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
        buttonn.setTextSize(15);
        buttonn.setId(i + 1);
        buttonn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rel_btn
                = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Rect bounds = imageView.getDrawable().getBounds();
        int scaledHeight = bounds.height();
        int scaledWidth = bounds.width();
        double scale;
        double differWidth = 0;
        double differHeight = 0;

        imageViewHeight = imageView.getHeight();
        imageViewWidth = imageView.getWidth();

        if (scaledHeight > scaledWidth) {
            scale = ((double) imageViewHeight / (double) scaledHeight);
            differWidth = (imageViewWidth - (scaledWidth * scale)) / 2;
        } else {
            scale = ((double) imageViewWidth / (double) scaledWidth);
            differHeight = (imageViewHeight - (scaledHeight * scale)) / 2;
        }

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int swidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
        int buttonWidth = swidth / 30;

        double a = ((double) (x11 + x22) / 2) * scale - buttonWidth + differWidth;
        double b = ((double) (y11 + y22) / 2) * scale - buttonWidth + differHeight;

        rel_btn.leftMargin = (int) a;
        rel_btn.topMargin = (int) b;

        rel_btn.width = 2 * buttonWidth;
        rel_btn.height = 2 * buttonWidth;
        buttonn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        buttonn.setLayoutParams(rel_btn);

        return buttonn;
    }
```

When the activity starts, this function is called in for loop (number of loop is depends on number of areas) to create buttons on the ImageView. When all buttons are created, user can click on one of any dynamic button to focus on the spesific area.

If the user click on any button, the createButton() function is called again (it doesnt necessary but it doesnt make an issue either) for some purposes.

The problem is height of ImageView is not fixed. At the first time of calling createButton() function, the height returns as greater than the normal height. Then if you call createButton() again, the height returns the normal value.

> imageViewHeight = imageView.getHeight();
>
> imageViewWidth = imageView.getWidth();

The class has 2-3 nested thread, so maybe this is cause of problem. But I tried lots of things like:

1. I used CountDownLatch to handle threads and functions
2. I used mImageView.post(new Runnable...) to be sure to call functions after imageView is created.
3. I called imageView.getHeight() lots of
   different places, but nothing is changed.

I keep the expression long, because I couldn't decided if the information is enough to understand. And as you realize, English is not my native. Thank you.

Edit: I forgot to mention: Below API 19, everything is cool (getHeight() value is returning as the normal size, either at the first time of calling createButton() methor or later ). API 20 and above, I get this error.

Comment: Try addOnGlobalLayoutListener() listeners like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8171014/4101990)

Comment: @MaheshB I tried but doesnt work. Same issue occurs.

Comment: why is it downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I luckily found the solution.. I use fullscreen mode at my app, but I didn't use AreaSelectActivity in fullscreen. After activity opened, status bar is coming down in a while. That's why height is changed but length is not. I put AreaSelectActivity in fullscreen mode and bum ! it is fixed now.