# getWidth() and getHeight() return 0 value

Tags: java, android

Hello I've created my personal view in android and when I want to get its dimension I get always 0 value, I've found that I should delay this action in my code, I have one question can I do this in this way? I get good dimension

```
Personalview myView = (Personalview)findViewById(R.id.myView);
myView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i("WIDTH",String.valueOf(myView .getHeight()));
        Log.i("HEIGHT",String.valueOf(myView .height()));
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: hard to imagine from so short fragment. what is and where initialised 'snake'. Too short code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getWidth() and getHeight() of View returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/getwidth-and-getheight-of-view-returns-0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getHeight returns 0 for all Android UI objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170915/getheight-returns-0-for-all-android-ui-objects)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `OnLayoutChangeListener`:

```
myView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                myView.removeOnLayoutChangeListener(this);

                // get dimensions now
            }
        });
```

This is a better approach than setting an arbitrary delay. You will get a callback when the bounds of the `View` changes due to layout processing. So you will get the proper dimensions inside the `onLayoutChange` callback. Don't forget the remove the listener after the first callback.

Comment: Do not remove the listener on first call. This won't get you the dimension everytime. Occasionally onLayoutChange will be called with 0/0 dimension on first call, but with dimension on second. Remove listener, when measured height/width > 0.