# Change size layout in code in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a question about resize layout. This is my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.log_in);


}
```

How can I set size my R.layout.log_in in this activity? I want set size to 400x300 but in activity not xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are your requirements but I prefer to set the dimension on the xml (if they're suppose to be fixed).

Anyway, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798867/android-how-to-programmatically-set-the-size-of-a-layout) can be useful.

The code used in the link:

```
// Gets linearlayout
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.numberPadLayout);
// Gets the layout params that will allow you to resize the layout
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
// Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*
params.height = 300;
params.width = 400;
```