# How to set height of a layout after the layout was already created

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layoutparams

I spent several hours trying to do this, but finally I gave up.

I have a LinearLayout. Inside of it I have another LinearLayout that is initially hidden. When some condition occurs, I need that hidden layout to be shown and the containing layout to expand its height in order to show the shown layout.

I can detect that the layout is shown, however, containing layout does not expand. The problem is that after containing layout is another layout that I need to be moved down so that the new layout can be seen.

This I have done at last:

```
                                sublay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                                layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
                                layout.requestLayout();
```

Of course, that did not work. How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798867/android-how-to-programmatically-set-the-size-of-a-layout have you gone through this question

Comment: Yes.. it did not work... it is strange though that layout.getLayoutParams().height is -1 initially

Comment: have you added height and width property initially to your xml design where you are adding visibility = false ?

Comment: it is showing -1 means you have not added height and width in xml

Comment: I have created container layout programmatically, not by XML, and I did: final LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); for it

Comment: And this for hidden layout: final LinearLayout.LayoutParams ll = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

Comment: is your container layout is a linear layout ?

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT add this to your container layout and a scrollview to see if it is working correctly

Comment: maybe, you just misspelled, and you needed to call sublay.setLayoutParams(lp); sublay.requestLayout(); instead of layout.setLayoutParams(lp); layout.requestLayout();

Comment: no....sublay has already params set as I wrote in the comment. What i need to do is to increase the container layout height because sublay was correctly height set. I can verify that because if I set the container layout height when I created it, height is correctly set and I can see sublay.

Answer (score 1):

Try
`sublay.getLayoutParams().height = MATCH_PARENT;
sublay.getLayoutParams().width = MATCH_PARENT;`

Comment: maybe layout is correctly expanded, but the other layout below does not move down