# Adjusting height of linear layout programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Whenever I try setting the height of a LinearLayout, I always get this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
```

Here is my code:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams  hide = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams  show = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);

driverMainOptions.setLayoutParams(hide);
mapDirections.setLayoutParams(show);
```

Is there a specific import statement I need for this to execute properly?

Comment: It seems that one of your layouts is a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: The type of `LayoutParams` a `View` has depends on its parent `View`, not what it itself is. Your `LinearLayout` appears to be in a `RelativeLayout`, and so has `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, not `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

Comment: @JuanCruzSoler The layouts I am modifying are Linear. The relative layout is pretty much the parent of all the objects, but the objects I want to manipulate are Linear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work

```
LinearLayout lLayout = new LineaLayout(context);
LayoutParams params = lLayout.getLayoutParams();

params.height = 200;
params.width = 200;
lLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

see the accepted answer at [Android: How to Programmatically set the size of a Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798867/android-how-to-programmatically-set-the-size-of-a-layout])

Comment: Ah okay. Would there be any way of setting an "alignParentBottom" value to false?

Comment: @purewatashi21 You need to make sure the `LayoutParams` are `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, then you can use: `params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 0);`.

Comment: @purewatashi21, exactly what Mike M. said, you have to use a RelativeLayout before you can use the attribute alignParentBottom.