# How can I make the width of a Constraint Layout negative?

Tags: java, android

I'm not sure if this is possible, or If I am approaching this challenge wrong. I am making a 2D Platformer, so when you hit the edge of the screen(Width), a new portion of the map would appear. Currently, I made single Images for each Portion of the map. Problem is, on larger devices, this would leave a lot of blank screen, and the Image would only fit a specific device.

Now I am wondering, can I make my ImageView (MAP) at a *negative X value* then when the character hits the edge, the map would move right (X would go higher).

I am using XML (Java is also fine), and I have NO CLUE how to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using constraint layout, you need to set `android:layout_width="0dip"`.
This will fit any image to its screen width.(Image width should be greater than screen horizontal width).
Apply some conditions something like,
If image width < screen width then call next image to remaining screen, else call next image for entire screen.
Hope it helps for code-flow.
:)

Answer (score 0):

You could use android:translationX or Android:translationY which actually support negative values. But in your particular case I think you are trying to use a nail clipper to cut your hair... You are using stuff that are not designed for that purpose. Using multiple big Image views can become a performance issue (I don't know about your particular case), I recommended you instead to be brave and make your own wiew and paint it dynamically (it can sound difficult but I'm sure will be easier than what you are trying), or make a comprehensive googling for a view meant for what you want.

Specifically for games you should try andengine lib or something like that, believe me... It would be easier in the end and you may earn something new :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to draw a layout (e.g. `RelativeLayout`) *larger* than your screen size, with an equal amount of padding on all sides.

For example, if you want to make a 50dp x 50dp `ImageView` appear from off the right hand side of the screen, your `RelativeLayout` would be 100dp taller and wider than your screen (50dp on each side). You could then position your `ImageView` at the far right of the `RelativeLayout`, and move it onto the visible area at will. So drawing something at -20dp, would actually be drawing it at 30dp in this example.

Programmatically [getting the screen size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4744499/608312) and [resizing a layout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6798938/608312) is very straightforward, and this approach would let you control your map loading in the manner you described.