# how to change th value of layout in MainActivity.java?

Tags: java, android, density-independent-pixel

i am using android studio
in x.xml, i set the layout_height=400dp

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="400dp"
      
</RelativeLayout>
```

in MainActivity.java,i use following code to get layer

```
relativelayout2=findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2);
```

i got the id of layout_height in MainActivity.java,

but how to change it to differents value ?

Comment: what exactly you are trying to achieve can you please elaborate??

Comment: I guess, this is what you're looking for
[Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798867/android-how-to-programmatically-set-the-size-of-a-layout)